# Rendering a DIV that is larger than the screen to an image using HTML2Canvas

Tags: html, html2canvas

I'm using HTML2Canvas to convert my `DIV` to a PNG. It is going well, but when my `DIV` is larger than the screen, only the visible part of the `DIV` in the screen is rendered in the image.

Is there any workaround so I can render the whole `DIV` into the image?

Here is my code:

```
html2canvas(divDrop, {
    onrendered: function (canvas) {
        imgMap.style.display = "";
        imgMap.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    },
    width: divDrop.clientWidth,
    height: divDrop.clientHeight
});
```

Comment: Did you check the `clientWidth` and `clientHeight` properties? Are these dimensions correct?

Comment: Yes I've checked them, they are current size of my DIV

Comment: So the client size of your div is greater than the window size, the rest of the canvas is filled with white color? When you change the size of the window, it is copying the windows size?

Comment: What about changing the size of the window itself to the size of the div?

Comment: Yes my DIV client size is bigger than window size and the rest of canvas is filled with white color

Comment: my DIV can grow in both sides (about several thousand pixels), so I cannot make window the same size as my DIV

Comment: It is limited to the window size. It is little bit strange trying to export so big div, and I need to ask why, you said yourself the rest of the div is not visible. But think about the little hack just before exporting you change the window size, and after exporting change it back.

Comment: please have a look this fiddler "http://jsfiddle.net/8ypxW/2083/" hope this works for you.

Comment: fiddle: We're truly sorry, but there is no such page.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8ypxW/2083/

Comment: above link works for me. let me know about yours.

Comment: yes I think it is working correctly both horizontally and vertically, what is the trick here?

Comment: sorry do not know, it just copy and paste code from unknown place. for now just enjoy

Answer (score 3):

As described in the comments, I'm posting the working link below:

**[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/8ypxW/2083/)**

```
$(function() { 
    $("#btnSave").click(function() { 
        html2canvas($("#widget"), {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                theCanvas = canvas;
                document.body.appendChild(canvas);

                // Convert and download as image 
                Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas); 
                $("#img-out").append(canvas);
                // Clean up 
                //document.body.removeChild(canvas);
            }
        });
    });
});
```